# Meaning of the eigenvector of the Hessian matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hessian-matrix

In Hessian-matrix sign test,  why the proof (links are in  bellow)  is always based on the eigenvectors? The study of the variation of a function $f(x,y)$  around the critical point can take any direction!
[Interpretation of eigenvectors of Hessian in context of local min/max/saddle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519353/interpretation-of-eigenvectors-of-hessian-in-context-of-local-min-max-saddle)
[Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of Hessian matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295571/eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues-of-hessian-matrix)